# javascript onclick event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my script here,

```
 <script type='javascript'>
 $(LastRow).find('#delete').attr('onclick','Comment_Delete(event,'+cID+')')
</script>

<input type="image" id="delete" border="0" src="../Resource/images/commentcross.jpg";" style="border-width:0px;">
```

i want control to be rendered as,

```
<input type="image" id="delete" border="0" onclick="Comment_Delete(event,1048);"  src="../Resource/images/commentcross.jpg";" style="border-width:0px;">
```

i.e. i want to bind `onclick` event to my `id=delete` tag.i have used my live as,

```
$(LastRow).find('#delete').live('click','Comment_Delete(event,'+cID+')')
```

but gettintg error in chrome as `TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: Is it possible to put a jsfiddle?

Comment: it is a row of my table , which contain image button.

Comment: try this javascript `document.getElementById('delete').setAttribute('onclick','Comment_Delete(event,1048)')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(LastRow).find('#delete').live('click', function() { Comment_Delete(event,cID ) } );
```

Comment: thanks alot friends now it is working.  $(LastRow).find('#delete').attr('onclick','Comment_Delete(event,'+cID+')')

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

```
$(document).find('#delete', LastRow).on('click', Comment_Delete('event',cID));
```

and this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#delete' Comment_Delete('event',cID));
```

Comment: $(document).find('#delete', LastRow).on('click', Comment_Delete('event',cID));
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on